# Mkv files random stops playing on my blu-ray player, Why?

Tags: hard-drive, video, usb-storage, blu-ray, matroska

I am a holder of LG BD390 Blu-ray player...it has always worked well but lately is giving me problems with reading mkv files from external hard drive.

Let me explain...

Lately I've noticed that while I'm playing a mkv file the player randomly stops play video and return to the menu, but I have not touched anything! It happens very frequently.

Initially I thought the problem was related to the mkv file that I was seeing, but then I noticed that the same problem occurred on all other mkv I had; so I came to suspect it might depend on the hard disk, I thought it was damaged, so I tried a new one but the problem continues to occur (both are 2TB HD with external power supply). As a last test I tried to put the mkv file on a USB key and in that case instead everything worked properly.

Among other things I tried to do a restore factory settings of the player but nothing has changed.

Have any of you ever had to deal with a problem like mine? Ever happened to anyone? What do you advise me to do?

Thank you in advance for any useful information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Matroska Video Files (*.mkv) Commonly are used on very good quality videos. Full HD or even UltraHD. These kind of resolutions needs some specific transfer rate between your drive and your Blu-Ray Player. One guess would be , that your external drive is unable to deliver the data on time to the blu-ray player with result the short pause of your video, until the device gets the next data to continue.

There are many reasons that can cause that, such as

1. a damaged usb/power cable,
2. damaged drive (as u said it happened to 2 of your hdds)
3. Blu-Ray's USB to not support this big transfer rates etc... (as u said it does play with a usb flash drive)
4. Drive's Speed is not enough to stream this kind of video file.

So based on your saying we exclude 2,3

I Would suggest you to run a speed test on both of your hdds, open these kind of files with VLC Player on a Computer and check the bandwidth. Then you will be able to check if you can stream this movie on your blu-ray player or not via your HDDs.

If your HDD's transfer rate is enough, then check your power/usb cables. Sometimes when the drives operate with less power have less performance... (Happened to me twice)

Comment: I will try, however the 2TB hard drive has always worked flawlessly, until a few weeks ago when mkv started to stops completely random while they are playing.

Comment: That's odd. It can be caused by Power deficiency. This occurs when there isn't enough power to keep electricity flowing in your hard drive disk, or its power supply becomes faulty.

Please do consider to connect your hard drive to your computer with the same Power Supply Cable, and the same USB Cable. Then sit, and watch the whole movie... if it randomly stops, there's issue with your hard drive. Otherwise it's Blu-Ray's Issue. 

However i'm pretty much confident that the issue is on your hard drive, since a flash drive, can stream this movie without issue.

Comment: Taking the tests I found that the problem occurs only when the HDMI cable is connected to the output of the player! If I unplug the HDMI cable from the player, playing mkv works without problems. How so?

Comment: Maybe you HDMI Cable is faulty, and cannot transfer this amount of data rate to your playback device, try using other hdmi cable,